# Multiplying integers represented as an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, endianness, multiplication

I'm trying to build a class, bigint, which represents large numbers in an array but I am having trouble creating a `*=` member function which multiplies this bigint with another bigint. I know there are already classes which achieve this but I'm trying to build my own as a learning exercise.

The digits of a biguint are stored in the array `std::size_t data[CAPACITY]` with the least significant digit stored in `data[0]` and the most significant digit in `data[CAPACITY-1]` (little endian). For example, if `CAPACITY=5`, then 12345 would be represented as `data[0]=5, data[1]=4, data[2]=3, data[3]=2, data[4]=1`.

I have successfully built constructors, addition functions, size functions, `<<` operator functions, `>>` operator functions, and `[]` operator functions. For example, the following code works.

```
int main()
{
    biguint b(423);
    biguint c(2363);
    b += c;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << b.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That will output:

```
2786
4
```

Onto the multiplication problem, this is the closest function I've come up with. It can correctly calculate bigints like 400*2 but fails at bigints like 400*20 since it rewrites `data[i]`.

```
void bigint::operator *= (const bigint &n)
{
    int carryover = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i < size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j < n.size(); ++j)
        {
            std::cout << data[i] << "*" << n[j] << "=";
            data[i] *= n[j];
            std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do long multiplication like this:

```
  109
*  12
 ____
  218
+1090
_____
 1308
```

I think the right way to do this would be to create a new bigint but I'm getting the error, `lvalue required as left operand of assignment`, when I try something like this:

```
void bigint::operator *= (const biguint &n)
{
    int carryover = 0;
    bigint ans(0);
    for (size_t i=0; i < size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j < n.size(); ++j)
        {
            ans[j] += data[i] * n[i];
            ans[j] += carryover;
            carryover = ans[j] / 10;
            ans[j] = ans[j] % 10;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is my approach correct at least? What is the correct way of multiplying two numbers stored as an little endian array?

For reference, this is how I coded the `+=` operator. I'm basically just doing elementary school addition by hand.

```
void bigint::operator += (const biguint &n)
{
    int carryover = 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i < CAPACITY; ++i)
    {
        data[i] += n[i];
        data[i] += carryover;
        carryover = data[i] / 10;
        data[i] = data[i] % 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should try to overload the `*` operator first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem but in a slow and inefficient way. I just add the first number to itself the second number of times. My syntax is a little strange since I haven't written `<, >, or ++` operators yet.  I will stick to this implementation for now since it is the only working implementation I have right now.

```
void biguint::operator *= (const biguint &n)
{
    biguint temp(*this);
    biguint i(1);
    biguint one(1);

    while (i.compare(n) != 0)
    {
        *this += temp;
        i += one;
    }
}
```